# Passing SQL to an Oracle bind variable

Tags: oracle, variables, bind

I need to execute something like:

```
select  
[very big SQL]  
where phone_number in(:SQL2)
```

Is it possible to use bind variable for SQL2?
I want to save the execution plan of the major SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary table and save `SQL2`'s results there prior to executing `SQL1`:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE mytemptable (id INT NOT NULL)

CREATE OUTLINE ol_sql1
ON
SELECT  *
FROM    sql1
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytemptable
        )

INSERT
INTO    mytemptable
SELECT  *
FROM    sql2

SELECT  *
FROM    sql1
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytemptable
        )
```

Comment: But the problem is that many users can execute this SQL at the same time

Comment: @Hec: which `SQL`? `SQL1`, `SQL2`, both?

Comment: OK i`ll describe it a bit more. here is a simple SQL (the real main sql in much more complicated ofcourse): [select * from phones where phone_number in(select column1 from temp_table1)]. many users executes the entire SQL but for each execute the system creates new temp table (so the inner SQL changed).

Comment: @Hec: the system will not create the new temp table, the system will fill the existing temp table with the new values. Your outer `SQL` won't change and hence can be outlined. Everything that changes is the data within the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Quassanoi's point. It sounds like you may not be familiar with temporary tables. [This](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_temporary_tables_sql.htm) is a good introduction.

You only create the table once. Then within a given session you first:

1. populate the temporary table
2. execute your query pulling from the temporary table
3. rollback.

There's no risk of conflicting/overlapping with another session's data.

Comment: also: step (3) can be COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 0):

If this query gets executed a lot of times, I wouldn't use a temporary table for it.

There is a 'trick' to bind an inlist, which Tom Kyte describes on his blog:

http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/06/varying-in-lists.html

I would bet on that being much more efficient.  It should be easy to prove with a SQL Trace.